# Same error in terminal is driving me nuts for python programs

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have been trying to execute programs in ubuntu terminal so that (in this case) the program running in the terminal will ask me for my d.o.b and then will print out a programmed response, but i have been coming up with the same line of error and i have no idea what to do here. i tried a different text editor but nothing seems to work! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
**Error

**.age_game.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '('

.age_game.py: line 2: 'y= int(raw_input("What is your d.o.b?"))**'**
```

The sample code is below, and i have tried a few different codes but the same error pops up

```
x = 0
y = int(raw_input("What is your d.o.b?"))
def reality(y):
     if y<=x:
         return "Stop lying!"
     else:
         return "Woah! You know your age now"
```

Comment: sorry about that! no the indentation seems right, it doesnt seem to be right. I ran it in python visualizer and it doesnt show any specific problems with teh code

Comment: The problem is when you run it on terminal right? With double-click?

Comment: Those look like *shell* error messages, not Python ones..

Comment: I am not sure what this error means and how i can fix it, if at all of i should use anything else to execute python programs?

Comment: Try invoking your script with Python: python age_game.py

Comment: @sanster9292 Yes py2exe for Python 2x and cx_Freeze for Python3x . Your codes looks fine.

Comment: hey, that command actually worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the terminal doesn't understand that your program is a python script yet, and it is trying to execute it with the default interpreter, which is /bin/sh.

Either start your script with `#!/usr/bin/python` on the first line and then run `chmod +x age_game.py` from the terminal to make it executable, and then invoke it with `./age_game.py`, or just invoke it with Python via `python age_game.py`

Answer (score 0):

You should tell your terminal to use the python interpreter to run your program.
Do it by adding `#!/usr/bin/python` at the start of your script, then you should enable executing of your script by running this command in the terminal

```
chmod +x <yourappname>.py
```